# Android ToolBar wont show title

Tags: android

My Custom ToolBar is not showing up the title

image:

[image]

My Main:

```
Toolbar toolbar_exit = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_simple_exit); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_exit);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Help");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

my Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.HelpActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="Work Stupid Title"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Activities.AtividadePrincipal" />
        </activity>
```

why its not showing? ive tried `this.setTitle` and other, nothing worked

Comment: Have you tried with toolbar_exit.setTitle("Your title");

Comment: toolbar_exit.setTitle("Help");

Answer (score 1):

Please be specific when you ask questions by posting your customized layout files and related java code.

Set your style theme's parent of type `.NoActionBar`? and set the following attributes.

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a custom layout for the action bar, then set text for the textview on the custom layout of the action actionbar. This is my code:

```
private void setCustomActionbarView() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    // kiem tra lai ham nay
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mActionBarView = mInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);

}
```

and my custom layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.orangestudio.mpromotion"
android:id="@+id/linBang"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textAcb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/home_khuyen_mai"
    android:textColor="@color/acb_text_color"
    app:font="@string/font_bold" />
```

Set the actionbar title:

```
View actionbarView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
TextView text =(TextView) actionbarView.findViewById(R.id.textAcb);
    text.setText("YOUR TITLE");
```